# How do I say 'For God's sake' in German?

Tags: english-to-german

How do I say 'For God's sakes' in German?

1. Um Gottes willen, warum bist du hingegangen?

Are there other alternatives for it?

Comment: When asking for translation, it's important to provide context because expressions don't map 1:1 from one language to the other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Um Gottes willen

is the correct translation. There are alternatives that can be used for the same, some very close, some not so close to the original meaning, like

> Um Himmels willen!

(For Heaven's sake!)

> Himmelherrgott!

(God in Heaven! coll.)

> Herrgott nochmal!

(coll.)

> Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn!

(rude and not very close)

> Heiligsblechle!

(example for a regional version, used mainly in the southwest of Germany)

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Note, however, that while the first two are indeed the literal translations, they are far less common in this context than the English phrase. In comparison, they have a rather milder "flavour" and don't really pack the amount of exasperation and sometimes even disgust a hearty "oh for god's sake!" can convey. Also, if you're interested in regional variants, in Bavaria we often say "Herrschaftszeiten", which usually sounds very exasperated indeed. :)

Comment: Warum in Gottes Namen bist du dahin gegangen.... geht auch noch

Comment: Note that in ‘um … willen’ the word _[willen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/willen)_ is not a noun, but a preposition (with genitive). Therefore, it is written with a small initial letter.

Comment: A preposition is always pre- ("before") its noun. "Um....willen" is a circumposition.

Comment: @Mac: I would go a step farther and argue that the first two cannot be used to translate "oh for god's sake!" at all.

Answer (score 4):

One that was missing:

> Meine Güte!

Answer (score 4):

Also missing:

> Zum Himmel [nochmal]

It's mostly used in questions

> Warum, zum Himmel, bist du da hingegangen?

or

> Zum Himmel nochmal, warum bist du da hingegangen?

There are also slight differences in the connotation: `zum Himmel` is more angry, `um Gottes willen` is more scared.

Answer (score 2):

> Verdammt nochmal!

Ist auch sehr beliebt, auch wenn das nicht die genaue Übersetzung ist.